# Iteration by groups or IDs

Tags: r

I am trying to iterate by groups or IDs in R and I cannot figure out how to do it in a simple way.

As an example I cannot figure out how to do the `Study_Time` column in the data frame.

```
ID  Gender
1   Male
1   Male
1   Male
2   Female
2   Female
2   Female
3   Male
3   Male
3   Male
```

I need to get this:

```
ID  Gender  Study_Time
1   Male    1
1   Male    2
1   Male    3
2   Female  1
2   Female  2
2   Female  3
3   Male    1
3   Male    2
3   Male    3
```

PS: I have tried with if else conditions but the real data comes from a survey with more than 50 study times. So I would need something more simple.

Comment: Use `ave` i.e. `with(df1, ave(ID, ID, Gender, FUN = seq_along))`

Comment: Thanks! @akrun. With ave() works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without the need to group by:

```
df$Study_Time <- unlist(mapply(function(i) seq_len(i), rle(as.numeric(df$Gender))$lengths))

#   ID Gender Study_Time
#1   1   Male          1
#2   1   Male          2
#3   1   Male          3
#4   2 Female          1
#5   2 Female          2
#6   2 Female          3
#7   3   Male          1
#8   3   Male          2
#9   3   Male          3
#10  3   Male          4
```

Or if you want to do it with group by:

```
df$Study_Time <- unlist(aggregate(Gender~ID, df, seq_along)$Gender)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(Study_Time = row_number())
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do with `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$Study_Time <- with(df1, ave(ID, ID, Gender, FUN = seq_along))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Study_Time := 1:.N, .(ID, Gender)]
```